# Get the distinct rows in an Excel table based on the latest modifiedDate

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Following is the table we have in the Excel. it contains duplicate entries of the tickets. we need to convert this excel table into another table having only unique rows having the latest Modified_Date

```
Tket Status Modified_Date
---- ------ -------------
5184 Active 20-07-2015
5184 Active 22-07-2015
5184 Closed 25-07-2015
5292 Active 22-07-2015
5292 Closed 23-07-2015
5480 Active 23-07-2015
5480 Closed 24-07-2015
```

Do i need to write macro code to achieve the same or is there any other alternate in MS Excel. I am using office 2013.

Comment: Do you need an automated solution? Because you can remove duplicate rows based off of a single column's values by using the Data Ribbon -> Remove Duplicates button.

Comment: I want to keep the distinct rows for each ticket whose modifiedDate is latest

Comment: It may be a bit overkill to automate this. Could you just sort the list by Modified_Date and then select which ever date ranges you want to remove duplicates in?

Comment: What if you try: 1) Remove Duplicates based on one column, or multiple.  Then you'll be left with unique rows.  2) Sort by Date, and just delete the non most recent entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a two simple step solution. (tried to use concept of SQL group-by clause)

Step 1: sort the entire range on

- Ticket ID ASC
- Modified Date DESC

then in a new column besides ModifiedDate use below formula

```
=IF(A2 = A1,"","1")


Ticket  Status  Modified    UniqueRows
5184    Closed  25-07-2015  1
5184    Active  20-07-2015
5184    Active  20-07-2015
5292    Closed  23-07-2015  1
5292    Active  22-07-2015
5480    Closed  24-07-2015  1
5480    Active  23-07-2015
```

My table starts at A1 cell.

since, after sorting I have all the tickets together, they form a group. within that group I sorted on modified date in descending order. thus I have the latest record on top for that ticket group.

I know the latest record (within the group) is on top, Thus, I compared the current ticket Id with the one above, if it changes then it is a new group and output value as 1.

now filter all the '1' and you have the records of your interest.

```
Ticket  Status  Modified    UniqueRows
5184    Closed  25-07-2015  1
5292    Closed  23-07-2015  1
5480    Closed  24-07-2015  1
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, This solution helped me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a non-VBA solution which is possible here; doing it in this way does not create a new table, though. Instead, it creates a column to check for whether each row is the latest date of that ticket number - you can then filter the column to show only matches; this column can then be copied to a new table if required.

Add a column, say column F, which will check whether that row has the latest modified-by date for the unique ticket number. Assuming Ticket Number is in column A, and the Modified-by date is in column C, type this in F2, and drag down [assuming data goes down only to row 14]:

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$14=A2,$C$2:$C$14,""))=C2
```

This is an Array Formula, which must be confirmed by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, rather than just ENTER. It works by checking each possible iteration of the function for each cell involved, one at a time. It then provides an array of possible results, and you must collapse that resulting array into a single value. Here, the IF statement checks each cell from A2 to A14 to see if it is equal to A2. If the Ticket numbers match, then it gives the date from column C, for each row, otherwise, it gives "". ie: if the only Ticket #'s which matched A2 were A2 and A5, the array of results would show up like this:

```
={DATE IN C2,"","",DATE IN C5,"","",...}
```

Now we need to collapse the array of results into a single value. Because we are working with numbers, doing this is fairly straightforward (collapsing an array of string results can be harder, because there are few functions in Excel which work with arrays of strings). Simply take the MAX value of the array, and it will return the latest date where there is a match for that Ticket number.

This is then turned into a value of either TRUE [this row contains the latest date for that Ticket Number], or FALSE [this row does not contain the latest date for that Ticket Number], by comparing the result from the MAX formula with the date in the current C2 cell. This method has the added benefit of leaving multiple matches where more than 1 line has the same latest modified-by date for that ticket number.

Then with that column of TRUE / FALSE values, filter for TRUE, and if necessary, simply copy & paste to another sheet.

However note that for your purposes VBA may be better as this is somewhat manual.